# Do some communities prefer indirect discourses to direct discourses?

Tags: semantics, discourse-analysis, discourse

Jamaliah Mohd. Ali, in her research paper, says, "the use of indirectness in communication is an important aspect of Malay community life because one of its main intentions is conflict avoidance" ([1995](https://jml.um.edu.my/article/view/3564):19).

Harnisch and David also say that if someone says "you are like the moon", most young Malaysians will get offended instead of taking it as a praise ([2015:434](https://books.google.com/books?id=SZCQCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA434)).

Is it a fact that some communities like Malaysians prefer indirect discourses to direct discourses? Which other communities prefer to be unassuming?

Comment: What is the linguistic question here?

Comment: my  question is  about about  direct  and  indirect  discourses among  the communitirs.Is it not  a linguistic question?

Comment: Not everything that involves words is a linguistic question. This is a cultural question, maybe suitable for a sociology or anthropology forum.

Comment: Discourses  are  a  part  of  linguistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're referring to what is known in social sciences as a [high-context culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-context_and_low-context_cultures), a concept put forth by Edward Hall in the 1970s. Hall considered some cultures to be "lower-context", i.e. requiring more explicit information in communication, than others, but this model has been criticized as lacking empirical evidence ([Cardon 2008](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240709593)).

The model of high-context vs. low-context may certainly be applied to the speech communities of languages, but not to languages themselves, because it is generally found that languages do not differ in their capabilities to express the same ideas; they just do it in different ways. The very fact you were able to word your question in English is one such piece of evidence.